# Aligning footer with the sidebar

Tags: css

I've completely at logger heads with how I can get this footer to align with the bottom of the sidebar if zero content is in the space between the header and footer.

Sticky footer is not the solution because I don't want it to be at the bottom of the window. But inline with the bottom of the sidebar instead.

Here is an image of what it should look like but without the coloured blocks there at the moment they push the footer down where it is now.

I can't provide much code as this is on my local server, and is segmented and broken down into different files for wordpress.

[screenshot http://s3.amazonaws.com/awesome_screenshot/2110547?AWSAccessKeyId=0R7FMW7AXRVCYMAPTPR2&Expires=1368128529&Signature=GjSmfhU6%2BZoYmSUj6oMEcvNXTEs%3D](http://s3.amazonaws.com/awesome_screenshot/2110547?AWSAccessKeyId=0R7FMW7AXRVCYMAPTPR2&Expires=1368128529&Signature=GjSmfhU6%2BZoYmSUj6oMEcvNXTEs%3D)

as you can see the above screenshot is how I want the sidebar and footer to be with no content there.

Here is another screenshot showing my current problem, you can see how it latch's on to the bottom of any content on the page and sticks just below it.

http://awesomescreenshot.com/015198m642

Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider add a jsfiddle

Comment: I'll try and break it down see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by adding position relative to my container, then adding position absolute and bottom 0 to my footer.

Thanks anyway for the help

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar needs a `float:right;` then create a div between sidebar and footer with `clear:both;`, have the css for your footer include `margin-top:-xx (whatever pixels the footer height is)`. You might also need to throw a `position:relative` on there.

http://jsfiddle.net/uuTDG/

Comment: at the moment the sidebar has a float right, that's how it is there at the moment. I've also got a clear float in there just above the footer. I'll try and add a jsfiddle

Comment: @Dannyw24 The footer, sidebar, and content divs must all be in the same container for this to work as well. I'll look at your fiddle when it's up.

Comment: They are all within a container aswell, My site is to big I think to put a jsfiddle out I'm gunna try and condense the issue

Comment: @Dannyw24 Please see my edit; try it with a clear div in-between sidebar and footer.